# Empty $_POST values with AJAX and RewriteEngine

Tags: php, ajax, apache, post, mod-rewrite

I have a problem on my Linux server with Apache. Whenever I post a form (or data) through AJAX POST it appears that the POST values are empty. I read already about it that it could be something wrong with the .htaccess file, but still haven't found a solution.

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/product\.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/product\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Inside my virtualhost:

```
<Directory /var/www/foldername>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I logged the form data in the browser so I know the data send to the AJAX request isn't empty.
But in the PHP file that needs to handle the POST request and send a mail, the POST values are empty.

This is how I post the data:

```
var data = $('#frmContact').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: data,
    success: function () {
        // success
    },
    error: function () {
        // problem
    }
});
```

Does anybody has a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added the code where I handle the AJAX request.

Comment: Use firebug of a developer tool available on your browser and see what it does when you submit the request.

Comment: I used Chrome developer tools and in the post request to the php file, the form data is available. (http://gyazo.com/289aa185cea7ec632db1e0b43c866072). I have no idea what else I should be looking for?

Comment: And this are the requests: 
http://gyazo.com/55bd48af1a1a0cc9981f52d58d22bb69

Comment: Offcourse, that worked! Thanks! I was so focused on finding the problem in the Rewrite rules that I forgot about the obvious... Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are redirecting URL's that contain `.php` which will result on an empty POST once its redirected, what you actually need is to use:

```
/mail
```

As it will internally redirect to the PHP and retain the post data.